# App removed from Google Play because of branch.io

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, branch.io

Our App which is being made on unity has been removed from Google Play Store and got these details in email :

> Your app is using the Branch IO SDK, which is uploading users Installed
>   Packages information to https://api.branch.io/v1/applist without a
>   prominent disclosure. Prior to the collection and transmission, it
>   must prominently highlight how the user data will be used, describe
>   the type of data being collected and have the user provide affirmative
>   consent for such use.

We went through our project and apparently we are not using any branch.io sdk explicitly in our app. We weren't able to find any fix on any forums. How can we find the issue and fix it? Please help.

Comment: Check your Appmanifest. Remove any irrelevant permission from there.

Comment: @SaadAnees That won't help. This is an EU data protection problem, not a OS app permission problem.

Comment: @Draco18s Please can you explain a bit? basically we have server in US setup to maintain data of the user. All the content in the app after finalizing is sent to the server so that user can be able to see it on cross devices. Thats creating any issue?

Comment: @UmairBhatti Its about as different as you can get. One is legal, the other is software. *Just because* you're in the US doesn't except you from EU law: if you have customers in the EU, you have to abide by EU law. This is why Value charges state sales tax or prices games differently in different regions. *`All the content in the app after finalizing is sent to the server so that user can be able to see it on cross devices. Thats creating any issue?`* Could be.

Comment: Also, GDPR has analog laws in the US, but GDPR is well known in how comprehensive and consumer friendly it is. The point is, if you are sending any data to a server for any reason you have to inform your users what that data is, how its used, and make a best effort at securing that data. Google can't tell what your doing with the data, it only sees that data is being sent and stored and does not see a disclosure. (And IANAL)

Answer (score 3):

This was part of a recent change the Google made related to GDPR. You should have gotten a warning email from Google as well as Branch regarding this.

You must remove all versions of your Android App (Active/Inactive/Archived) that have the Android Branch SDK version < 2.11.1.

Once you remove these versions, Google should place your App back onto the Play Store.

Here is a guide on removing older versions of your App: https://branch.app.link/apk-removal-guide.

If you run into any issues, please write into support@branch.io. Thanks.